Copy hyperlinks from one column to another in google sheets
Please help me with the script I want to run automated to copy hyperlinks from one column to other except from first row in google sheets.
function copyHyperlinks() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('1 απαντήσεις φόρμας');
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange('U:U'); // Replace 'A:A' with your source column
  const targetRange = sheet.getRange('T:T'); // Replace 'B:B' with your target column
  const values = sourceRange.getValues();

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) { // Start loop from row 2 (index 1)
    const link = values[i][0].getLinkUrl();
    if (link) {
      targetRange.getCell(i + 1, 1).setHyperlink(link, values[i][0]);
    }
  }
}

Thank you very much.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to copy the hyperlinks of the cell from column "U" to column "T" using Google Apps Script.
From your showing script, I guessed that your hyperlink is set to the whole cell.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Please set your sheet name.
function copyHyperlinks() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('###');
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange('U2:U' + lastRow);
  const targetRange = sheet.getRange('T2:T' + lastRow);
  const src = sourceRange.getRichTextValues();
  const dst = targetRange.getRichTextValues().map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => {
    const link = src[i][j].getLinkUrl();
    return link ? c.copy().setLinkUrl(link).build() : c;
  }));
  targetRange.setRichTextValues(dst);
}


When this script is run, the hyperlinks of column "U" are copied to column "T".

Note:

As an important point, this script copies only the hyperlinks. So, the cell values are not copied because of your showing script. So, if column "T" has no cell value, the hyperlinks are not copied. Please be careful about this.

If you want to copy both the hyperlinks and the cell values, how about the following modification?
function copyHyperlinks() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('1###');
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const sourceRange = sheet.getRange('U2:U' + lastRow);
  const targetRange = sheet.getRange('T2:T' + lastRow);
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
}



References:

getRichTextValues()
setRichTextValues(values)

